# File Upload: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0

Tags: flutter, parse-platform, flutter-web, parse-server

I have upload a file to server, but always return this erro:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at createStrictSyntaxError (/home/andre/projetos/rifa/parse-server/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:158:10)
    at parse (/home/andre/projetos/rifa/parse-server/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)
    at /home/andre/projetos/rifa/parse-server/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (/home/andre/projetos/rifa/parse-server/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
    at done (/home/andre/projetos/rifa/parse-server/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/home/andre/projetos/rifa/parse-server/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:387:35)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1317:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
```

My client code to send is in Flutter:

```
Future<void> alterarImagemRifa() async {
    var img = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    ParseFileBase parseFile;
    if (kIsWeb) {
      ParseWebFile file = ParseWebFile(null, name: null, url: img.path);
      await file.download();
      parseFile = ParseWebFile(file.file, name: 'imagens/rifa_${rifa.id}');
      // parseFile = ParseWebFile(await img.readAsBytes(), name: 'imagens/rifa_${rifa.id}', debug: true);
    } else {
      parseFile = ParseFile(File(img.path), name: 'imagens/rifa_${rifa.id}');
    }

    obj.set('imagem', parseFile );
    var resp = await obj.save().catchError(erroSnack);
    if(!resp.success)
      return erroSnack('Não foi possível enviar o arquivo ao servidor', StackTrace.current);
    rifa.imagem = parseFile.url;
  }
```

I not have experience in parse-platform any help would be very nice

Comment: If you upload a file using the API directly (maybe try out via dashboard), does it work? Just to make sure that the Parse Server is properly configured.

Comment: that error is almost always a result of an invalid input to a JSON.parse() or JSON.stringify() call. I don't see those functions being called in your code - so it must be in the underlying library. However, it would suggest that your file name or rifa.id is invalid.... can you set a breakpoint an inspect ?